# Apache JMeter Regular Expressions Extractor Error

Tags: regex, apache, xmlhttprequest, jmeter, beanshell

I have made an HTTP Request to a webpage and it respond successfully with a VAST code (XML) Afterwards I tried to use Apache JMeter Regular Expressions Extractor for Extracting a URL from the **MediaFile** tag in the responded XML code . but it doesn't work.

Here is the responded data (VAST XML):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<VAST version="2.0">
  <Ad id="brightroll_ad">
    <InLine>
      <AdSystem>BrightRoll</AdSystem>
      <AdTitle></AdTitle>
      <Impression><![CDATA[http://brxserv-22.btrll.com/v1/epix/6835714/3858435/84416/140363/AbQ93_XgMgCcRUTi_JAAFJwAACJEsAOuADAAAAAAAiyel-GCNFFg/event.imp/r_64.aHR0cDovL2Iuc2NvcmVjYXJkcmVzZWFyY2guY29tL3A_JmMxPTgmYzI9NjAwMDAwNiZjMz04NDQxNiZjND0zODU4NDM1JmM1PTIwNDYzJmM2PTY4MzU3MTQmYzEwPTE0MDM2MyZjdj0xLjcmY2o9MSZybj0xNDE0NDEwMTg1JnI9aHR0cCUzQSUyRiUyRnBpeGVsLnF1YW50c2VydmUuY29tJTJGcGl4ZWwlMkZwLWNiNkMwekZGN2RXakkuZ2lmJTNGbGFiZWxzJTNEcC42ODM1NzE0LjM4NTg0MzUuMCUyQ2EuMjA0NjMuODQ0MTYuMTQwMzYzJTJDdS45NjguNjQweDM2MCUzQm1lZGlhJTNEYWQlM0JyJTNEMTQxNDQxMDE4NQ]]></Impression>
  <Impression><![CDATA[http://rc.rlcdn.com/361686.gif]]></Impression>
  <Creatives>
    <Creative id="140363" sequence="1">
      <Linear>
        <Duration>00:00:30</Duration>
        <TrackingEvents>
          <Tracking event="midpoint"><![CDATA[http://brxserv-22.btrll.com/v1/epix/6835714/3858435/84416/140363/AbQ93_XgMgCcRUTi_JAAFJwAACJEsAOuADAAAAAAAiyel-GCNFFg/event.mid]]></Tracking>
          <Tracking event="complete"><![CDATA[http://brxserv-22.btrll.com/v1/epix/6835714/3858435/84416/140363/AbQ93_XgMgCcRUTi_JAAFJwAACJEsAOuADAAAAAAAiyel-GCNFFg/event.end]]></Tracking>
        </TrackingEvents>
        <AdParameters></AdParameters>
        <VideoClicks>
          <ClickTracking><![CDATA[http://brxserv-22.btrll.com/v1/epix/6835714/3858435/84416/140363/AbQ93_XgMgCcRUTi_JAAFJwAACJEsAOuADAAAAAAAiyel-GCNFFg/event.click]]></ClickTracking>
        </VideoClicks>
        <MediaFiles>
          <MediaFile type="application/x-shockwave-flash" apiFramework="VPAID" height="360" width="640" delivery="progressive">
            <![CDATA[http://shim.btrll.com/shim/20141023.75835_master/Scout.swf?type=VPAID&hidefb=true&asset_64=aHR0cDovL3J0ci5pbm5vdmlkLmNvbS9yMS41NDQ1OTU0ZDA5ZTY4OS40MjIxNTcxODtjYj0xNDE0NDEwMTg1O3NpdGVpZD0zODU4NDM1bGluZWl0ZW04NDQxNg&vid_click_url=&config_url_64=&h_64=YnJ4c2Vydi0yMi5idHJsbC5jb20&dn=-&e=p&p=6835714&s=3858435&l=84416&ic=140363&ii=20463&iq=t&cx=&x=AbQ93_XgMgCcRUTi_JAAFJwAACJEsAOuADAAAAAAAiyel-GCNFFg&adc=false&t=33&si=&vh_64=Z2VvLXJ0YnNlcnYtdjIuYnRybGwuY29t&apep=0.05&hbp=0.01&view=vast2]]>
          </MediaFile>
        </MediaFiles>
      </Linear>
    </Creative>
  </Creatives>
</InLine>
```

and Here is the settings which I have used.

```
Reference Name: mediaFileUrl_VASTAdTagURI
Regular Expression: <MediaFile type="application//x-shockwave-flash" apiFramework="VPAID" height="360" width="640" delivery="progressive"><([^"]+)http:\/\/([^"]+)]]>>
Template: $1$$2$
Match No.: -1
Default Value: No mediaFileUrl_VASTAdTagURI
```

The result is always (No mediaFileUrl_VASTAdTagURI). any clue about the problem with the Regular Expression.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to capture, just the URL?

Comment: i think your +'s are being greedy, try adding some ?

Comment: @l'L'l : i'm trying to extract the last URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter provides [XPath Extractor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) to deal with XML and XHTML data. It can also work for HTML but you'll have to check `Use Tidy` box so JMeter could use [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) to work against HTML.

XPath expression to extract contents of CDATA should look something like:

```
//MediaFile/text()[2]
```

See [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) for more details. Few tools which can help in building/debugging XPath expressions:

- [XPath Checker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpath-checker/) Firefox add-on
- [FirePath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/) Firefox add-on
- [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) JMeter's listener provides XPath Tester as well

Comment: This post was very helpful. the exact right XPath was
**//MediaFile[1]**

Also i was printing the result in the Beanshell like 
String mediaFileUrl_VASTAdTagURI_1_g2 = vars.get ("mediaFileUrl_VASTAdTagURI_1_g2"); 
and printing the string afterwards in the Return. but whenever i use the Bean shell it stop working.